# The truth value of a raster is ambiguous. Invalid use of raster with Boolean operator or function

Tags: arcpy, raster

I'm having trouble with an if/else statement in my for loop.

I have a raster Vmax with a constant value, another raster V which has a value of 0 in the beginning and will change during execution of the loop. Furthermore I load two text files with rain and ET-data. The idea is to calculate a recharge depending on the change of V which in turn depends on rain and ET. So something like that in a loop:

```
AET_t = PET*(V/Vmax)
V_tt = V + prec - AET_t
if V_tt > Vmax:
    recharge = V_tt - Vmax
    V = Vmax
else:
    recharge = 0
    V = V_tt
```

This is my code:

```
#import modules and packages
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
import os.path

#set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\kern\Documents\model\test_area"

#load input rasters
Vmax = Raster(r"\input.gdb\Vmax")
V = Raster(r"\input.gdb\V")

#check if Spatial Analyst extension is available
arcpy.CheckExtension("Spatial")
#retrieve license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

#open rain and PET textfile
rain = open("rain.txt")
pet = open("Epot.txt")
#create list of daily rain and PET data values
rain_list = rain.readlines()
pet_list = pet.readlines()


from itertools import izip, count
for i, p, et in izip(count(),rain_list, pet_list):
    prec = CreateConstantRaster(p, "FLOAT", "5", Vmax)
    PET = CreateConstantRaster(et, "FLOAT", "5", Vmax)
    output_aet = r"C:\Users\kern\Documents\model\test_area\AET.gdb"
    outfile_aet = os.path.join (output_aet, "aet" + str(i))
    output_re = r"C:\Users\kern\Documents\model\test_area\recharge.gdb"
    outfile_re = os.path.join (output_re, "re" + str(i))
    AET_t = PET*(V/Vmax)
    AET_t.save(outfile_aet)
    prj_file = r"C:\Users\kern\Documents\model\model_input_5x5\a_aplis.prj"
    arcpy.DefineProjection_management(outfile_aet, prj_file)
    V_tt = V + prec - AET_t
    recharge = Con(V_tt > Vmax, V_tt - Vmax, 0)
    recharge.save(outfile_re)
    if recharge > 0:
        V = Vmax
    else:
        V = V_tt

rain.close()
pet.close()
```

And this is the error:

File "C:\Users\kirn\Documents\MSc_Arbeit\model\test_area\WaterBalance.py", line 46, in 
    if recharge > 0:
ValueError: The truth value of a raster is ambiguous. Invalid use of raster with Boolean operator or function. Check the use of parentheses where applicable.

It seems the problem is the V = Vmax and V = V_tt. But how can I assign Vmax and V_tt respectively to V in another way?
I found this https://geonet.esri.com/thread/79949 but couldn't really make head of it.

Comment: At the end, what is the intended meaning of a Python `if` statement that compares a *raster* to a constant??  Python is gently trying to tell you that this is nonsense.  You probably wanted to use a raster calculation (using `Con`) at this juncture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question it appears that you want to assign the values of each cell of `V` based on the value of `rainfall` at that cell. `arcpy` doesn't allow you (as a `numpy` array would) to compare a raster to a constant.

Also note that in each iteration of your loop V is being completely overwritten, and then the results aren't being saved anywhere, so once you get to the end of the function the raster `\input.gdb\V` won't have changed, and the value of `V` will be whatever value was written in the last iteration.

To resolve the error you're getting you can use the `CreateConstantRaster` method again to create a zero raster, and then a `Con` statement to compare and produce an output on a cell by cell basis:

```
zeros = CreateConstantRaster(O, "INTEGER", "5", Vmax)
V = Con(recharge > zeros, Vmax, V_tt
V.save("path/to/iteration/result")
```